# How do I fix the "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()" error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I'm trying to create a database using PHP and MySQL but keep getting an error:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()".

I've looked around and have seen and tried implementing the suggested fixes:

I have uncommented the lines:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

I have made sure the `ext` destination is correct as well.

I have also added the `libmysql.dll` to the `C:Windows\System32\` destination.

However, I still have the error.

This is the database I'm trying to run:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:8088';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
$sql = 'CREATE Database test_db';
$retval = mysqli_query($conn,  $sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create database: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Database test_db created successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is my PHPInfo:

http://jsfiddle.net/0munz085/

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Btw, the connection comes first in `mysqli_` --- `$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );`

Comment: Did you restart all services after making those changes? Maybe even reboot?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated now.

Comment: See comment #2. Did you?

Comment: Yes I was restarting Apache after every change I made.

Comment: Which webserver, Xampp, Wamp? If it's Wamp, I myself had to reboot Windows before anything worked, after "installing" it. What Windows do you have? If Wamp; there are different install versions for different Windows platforms.

Comment: I am using neither. I have Windows 7 Professional and am using Apache 2.4, MySQL and PHP 5.6.6.

Comment: Well there you have it; install a Webserver.

Comment: You're welcome. Check out http://www.wampserver.com/ and https://www.apachefriends.org/ and remember to reboot after installing it. Wamp has different versions for different Windows version, so choose the right one, good luck. *Cheers*

Comment: One more question, will it interfere with my current setup or will it be in its own thing.

Comment: That I couldn't say; I never had to re-install over Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Your Server Administrator.
they will help you to fix this problem. it is may be that MySQL is not installed correctly on your server.

Comment: Sorry, I should of mentioned that it is on a local server.

Comment: oh ok do you installed xampp or wampp on your system? MySQL and phpMyAdmin running on your pc?

Comment: I am using Apache 2.4, MySQL and PHP 5.6.6, I am not using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: search for xampp. it is a bundle all you need

Comment: download XAMPP app if you don't have that.

Comment: I am currently in training at my work and they want me to do it using the 3 I mentioned.